# Redirect after checking in Nuxt Asyncdata

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am running Nuxt and I have the below function. I want to check if authenticated then redirect to the login page if not. I am getting the error `window is undefined` This make since because it is my understanding that `asyncdata()` is evaluated server side. What is the correct way to redirect. I tried to use the redirect method in `context` but it just brings up my 404. Thanks

```
 async asyncData(context) {
    if (!context.authenticated) {
      window.location = `${config.url}/sign_in`;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`context` has a redirect function. [Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context)

```
 async asyncData(context) {
    if (!context.authenticated) {
      context.redirect(`${config.url}/sign_in`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Will not it cause the `Error: Redirected when going from "/XXX" to "/XXX" via a navigation guard.` error?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is probably for v1.

For Nuxt v2:

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ redirect }) {
    redirect('/page');
  }
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/#redirect